# Jquery Spinner arrows not loading (visibility)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, themeroller

The up and down arrows on the spinner are not showing and I am unsure why.
All other UI images seem to be loading besides these arrows.
Here is a website

[Website Link](http://fairyringspores.com/Products/GetProductDetails_View?ProductID=52&class=imageLink)

Comment: there is a a issue in image url, you need to add images in jquery ui css folder or , if the url is wrong then make it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason those images don't show, is because they aren't found in the path that you are specifying. Either you have forgotten to upload them, or you've uploaded them to the wrong directory.

Comment: Can you / someone please elaborate? The demo on the jQuery UI site doesn't include any details about the images.