# jQuery spinner arrows not visible

Tags: jquery, css, nuget, vs-community-edition, jquery-ui-spinner

I have seen a previous post on this [Jquery Spinner arrows not loading (visibility)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348964/jquery-spinner-arrows-not-loading-visibility)

but I still can't seem to load or see the spinner button images, although the spinner works fine. The css file path is: wwwroot/lib/jquery.ui.combined/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
and the images are in: wwwroot/lib/jquery.ui.combined/Content/themes/base/images.

I have had no problem in the past using jquery ui and spinners. I again used NuGet (with VS cummunity edition 2015) to get the jquery ui package, which now seems to load things into my windows users folder, so I just dragged the package into my solution. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You should share the code you have written unless you expect anyone to guess the reason why it isn't working. Better yet a demo. Read up on how to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use Nuget to install Jquery-Ui 1.12.1

The package is Buggy.

I have verified that. The package include a correct Jquery UI JavaScript file for 1.12.1 but is missing the ingredients of the structure and theme files, and it includes Completely WRONG Style Sheets from the older 1.11.4 and 1.12.0

I had to fix them in my project file individually.

What pointed me in this direction to investigate Nuget, was a ticket I opened related to a wrong Dialog cancel text that overflow the Cancel icon, and they pointed me to a mismatch in the style sheet versions, and here you go.

Just download the correct Stable style sheets and script package from
http://jqueryui.com/

then Upack the Zip file, and use VS Add-Existing to include the correct images and style sheets to the proper folders under Content/themes/base

The new structure for the Style Sheets is:

- jquery-ui.css  contains all the necessary styles for all Jquery UI
  elements
- jquery-ui.structure.css contains the core ui without the
  theme
- jquery-ui.theme.css contains the theme

so jquery-ui = jquery-ui.structure + jquery-ui.theme

This way, if you need to use your own custom theme, you can use the jquery-ui.structure along with your theme.

Hope this helps anyone facing the same problem we faced with the Nuget package

Answer (score 0):

As per the answers, to the linked question, the answer is really simple.

`http://fairyringspores.com/Content/images/ui-icons_6da8d5_256x240.png` The image was not found, therefore it does not load anything.

> The reason those images don't show, is because they aren't found in the path that you are specifying. Either you have forgotten to upload them, or you've uploaded them to the wrong directory.

So, to solved the problem look inside this `wwwroot/lib/jquery.ui.combined/Content/themes/base/images` folder for an image `ui-icons_6da8d5_256x240.png` if it's not there, download a copy of jquery UI, copy and paste the image in question to the folder above.

Comment: Thanks @Val. I am pretty sure that it isn't that simple. The image is there: I can set it as a background to a div. I have a project with the same folder structure which works. If I move or rename the image, the image doesn't show, but the span tags within the <a> tags have been created by the ui jquery. In the broken project, those span tags do not even get created, although the image does exist in the right place.

Comment: I think it might be something to do with the ordering of scripts/css. Here is a comparison of the 2 projects' ![folder structures and css/script links](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ap7cpyMPzrWPnS4Aanisusu589cR) . Project AGT works. I can add some code when I work out how to do that.

Comment: I am using VS Community 2015 Update 3 . I created a new Core MVC Web Application project and using Bower added JQuery 2.2.0 and JQuery-ui 1.12.1. I added the relevant css and script links to the _Layout.cshtml page. I added <input id="testSpinner" /> to a .cshtml page with <script>$(function () {  $('#testSpinner').spinner(); }); </script>. When run there are no errors and the spinner works but no button icons are visible. Style inspector shows that the <span class="ui-button-icon.. containers for these have not been created.

Comment: Line 6875 of jquery-ui.js to _addClasses ui-button and ui-widget to the parent <a> element did not get called. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Send me a link of your site, I will debug it for you. and let you know where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Val. These are not published sites yet. I just followed the steps above (several times to see where the problem starts) using Visual Studio. Every time I create a new project of that type I get the same problem. I haven't had time to try further debugging yet and have got round it for now using bootstrap, font-awesome and a few lines of javascript/jquery instead of jquery-ui. If following the above steps doesn't reproduce the same problem then it must be something I'm doing wrong.