# Why are the jQuery UI Spinner arrow buttons not showing?

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

After implementing the simplest boilerplate version of the jQuery UI [Spinner Widget](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/), the up- and down-arrow-buttons were not showing. Clicking the spot where they should appear caused the Spinner events to fire and the number to increment/decrement, but no buttons were visible.

I found some related (unhelpful) questions on SO (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679184/jquery-spinner-arrows-not-visible) and less [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348964/jquery-spinner-arrows-not-loading-visibility)) and one on the jQuery Forums ([here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/spinner-not-working-buttons-are-hidden)). That last thread mentioned possible Bootstrap conflicts.

I am using both Bootstrap and jQuery (UI) in my project.

Sample HTML

```
<input id="spinner" name="spinner">
```

and JavaScript

```
$( "#spinner" ).spinner({
  min: 0,
  step: 100000,
});
```

were nothing fancy, even though there was some custom CSS going on besides that, obviously.

Attempting to style using jQuery UI's provided CSS classes did not help. Doing something like

```
.ui-spinner-button {
  color: white !important;
  background: black;
}
```

did turn the buttons' background black, but the arrows were still not visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

If you encounter this problem and you are using both Bootstrap (v4) and jQuery (v1.12), try switching the order, in which their **JavaScript** (*not* CSS, strange, as it may seem) is loaded, specifically **have jQuery be loaded after Bootstrap**.

### Caveats

This may or may not cause issues where then jQuery interferes with Bootstrap functionality. Although, so far, I had no issues like this.

### Why?

After some digging and inspecting in the browser, I found that there was a style being applied to the button elements (`<a>`-tags) by Bootstrap, namely the following (coming from _reboot.scss):

```
a:not([href]) {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This seemed to mess with my attempts to force a different CSS onto the buttons.

The thread poster in the jQuery Forum mentioned above also found Bootstrap to be the problem, so I tried messing with the import orders. Strangely enough, having the jQuery UI CSS load after the Bootstrap CSS changed nothing. When I switched the JavaScript imports it worked (CSS import order can stay the same).

Why that is the case, I hope someone else can tell. I just hope, this helps someone pulling their hair, as I did.